# PHP foreach function problem

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v){

  foreach ($v as $e => $a){
     if($a == 1){break;} 
     //if $e has all 1's not just a single 1 (how to code it ?)
  }

}
```

how can I tell the first `foreach` function to break when `$e` has **all** `1`'s

Obviously this is not the actual code I'm using but its very similar, I need to walk through a two dimensional array and record the keys (`$e`) when their value (`$a`) is `1`.

The above code finishes right after the first 1 : (

*note: my array is not necessarily composed of numeric keys!*

There maybe much better ways of tackling this problem.. any ideas?

Thank you so much!

example:

```
Array
(
    ["ny"] => Array
        (
            [col0] => ""
            [col1] => ""
            [col2] => ""
            [col3] => ""
            [col4] => ""
            [col5] => ""
        )

    ["chicago"] => Array
        (
            [col0] => "1"
            [col1] => "1"
            [col2] => "1"
            [col3] => "1"
            [col4] => "1"
            [col5] => "1"
        )
)
```

I would like it to stop right after going through chicago.

Comment: Can you remove the break and add the value to a temp array instead?

Comment: You COULD try: array_unique($v) and check if it has 1 item with that specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v){ 
    if (count(array_diff($v, array(1))) == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You sneaky bastard, nice one and probably far more efficient than my method.

Comment: @Kevin - It's only a single count() on the subset of values, so it should be faster... though the array_diff() may be marginally slower than array_search() as array_search() will stop searching on the first match it finds

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that array_search doesn't solve this problem (needs to check if the array is completely 1's).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a 100% sure on what you want but would this fit your problem?

```
$totala = 10;
$numa = 0;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v){
    foreach ($v as $e => $a){
        if($a == 1){
            $numa++;
        }
        if($numa == $totala) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way it will break when the amount of times 1 has been found is the same as you set the total to. (10 in this example.)

Comment: This actually could work, would it break the outer loop as well?

Comment: If you use `break 2;` it will. The 2 specifies that it has to break through 2 loops instead of just the deepest one.